# Should we use LDA algorithm on "titles" or content?

Tags: machine-learning, lda, document-classification

I was working with LDA for document classification. I am confused in one part.
Should we use LDA for classification using document Title, or document content? 
I have a huge set of documents, and using LDA on content keeps throwing MemoryError for even a small number of topics(~5-10).

I understand that it requires 8*num_topics*dictionary_size bytes of memory, which is probably the reason it runs out of memory. It works better on the title of the documents.

Should I use LDA for topic, and some other algorithm like Word2Vec for content?